# Flatten an subarray and transform its values in key and also in value of the new array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following multidimensional array:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2007
        [1] => 318
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2001
        [1] => 307
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1993
        [1] => 306
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2011
        [1] => 285
    )
)
```

and would like to transform it in:

```
Array (
  [2007] => 318,
  [2001] => 307,
  [1993] => 306,
  [2011] => 285
)
```

Also the value of key[0] of the subarray will be the key of the new array and value of key[1] of the subarray will be the value of the new array.

I tried that, but only success:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($chart05 as $items) {
    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $items);
}
```

and this as well:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    foreach($v as $value) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
```

but none give me the expect result.

Then I would like to transform the new array in a string just like that:

```
[2007,318], [2001,307], [1993,306], [2011,285]
```

Here I'm not sure, but I think implode would work. What do you guys think?

I would appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($chart05 as $items) {
    $newArray[$items[0]] = $items[1];
}
```

Wil create the array structure you want.

However for the string output, i believe you dont want to change the original array, just json_encode it:

```
echo json_encode($chart05);
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/tYxECS